# Qu'est-ce qu'une « descente en sous-sol » ?

Tags: sens, expressions, prépositions

Dans une chanson de Johnny Hallyday ([*4m<sup>2</sup>*](https://youtu.be/Kxbjb0ZILiM?t=78) ds. *Mon pays c'est l'amour*, 2018, Warner Music France) on trouve le couplet suivant :

> J'ai des envies de ville 
>  Et de fumées d'usines 
>  J'ai des
>   désirs d'alcool 
>  Oui, [descente](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/descente) [en](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en/0) [sous-sol](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sous-sol)

Peut-on m'expliquer ce qu'est une « descente en sous-sol » ; est-ce associé à l'effet de l'alcool ou à un état d'esprit plus général ; l'emploi de la préposition *en* réfère-t-il à quelque chose de particulier ; s'agit-il d'une expression consacrée ?

Answer (score 1):

Premièrement les véritables paroles sont les suivantes:

> J'ai des envies de ville
> Et de fumées d'usines
> J'ai des désirs d'alcool
> Descente en sous-sol
>
> Source: [genius.com](https://genius.com/Johnny-hallyday-4m2-lyrics)

Ensuite pour répondre à la question *"Descente en sous-sol"* selon mon interprétation personnelle est ici associé à l'effet de l'alcool (qui permet au passage de rimer avec ce dernier). Faisant allusion à l'époque où l'alcool était conservé dans les sous-sol pour des questions de **conservation**.

Comment: Les véritables paroles, il n'y a que le « oui » qui diffère dans l'extrait ; pourquoi seraient-elles davantage véritables que d'autres ? Par ailleurs, je note que pour l'[autre chanson](https://genius.com/Johnny-hallyday-je-ne-suis-quun-homme-lyrics) à propos de laquelle j'ai posé une question, on a pas l'accord avec _rêvé_ et on a le pronom _on_ plutôt que la préposition _en_, ce qui est plus cohérent en effet, et on a l'accord à _noyée_...

Comment: Elles sont véritables car ce sont les paroles officielles, ce n'était pas une critique négative. Je pense juste qu'avant d'étudier des paroles, il est pratique de se plonger sur les bonne pour éviter une quelconque mauvaise compréhension de ces dernières ;)

Comment: Je comprends, merci, et vous avez raison qu'il est important d'avoir les bonnes paroles mais je ne saisis toujours pas ce qui vous fait dire que ce sont les paroles _officielles_, je lis sur ce site que c'est _community driven_ etc. J'en conclus que vous avez accès à d'autres sources d'information qui vous permettent de l'affirmer... J'ai donné des indications à partir de ces paroles du site dont vous parlez en commentaire dans mon autre question sur l'autre chanson, de quoi donner du fil à retordre à plusieurs puisqu'on a l'accord avec noyée mais pas avec rêvé...